# iText 7 : Set text field once even if it exists multiple times with the same name

Tags: java, itext7

I have a PDF document with multiple text fields with the same name.

I would like to set the value once (`field.setValue("text")`) and the value to appear for every occurrence of the field. The fields may be in the same page or different pages (and obviously, the same document).

When there is only one such field, PDF generation is fine. If more than one, all fields appears empty. If I disable flattening, I can see the text in every field (though only after clicking on the field - weird...).

Here is the [test PDF](https://drive.google.com/file/d/16IgO74D4zwbSpO0Di0PympYZhYYPDUz9/view?usp=sharing).

---

**EDIT**:

The issue seems to happen only when I set the font of the field. You can reproduce using [this font](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Tqx1ihUkll542ZzfurGqRMse3lCc9X10/view?usp=sharing) and the following code:

```
PdfFont font = PdfFontFactory.createFont("src/main/resources/fonts/Arimo-Regular.ttf", PdfEncodings.IDENTITY_H);
PdfFormField textField = acroForm.getField("test");
textField.setValue("שלום", font, 11.0f);
```

Comment: Already when I looked into [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54107835/1729265), I got the impression that itext 7's form field appearance generation does not properly support multi-widget fields, not only for push buttons (which that previous question focused on) but for other form field types, too. Nonetheless, would you share a sample pdf to test with?

Comment: I added the PDF to the question. It's hard to believe that iText 7 doesn't support this simple use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## The updated question

Using the font provided by the OP and the `setValue` overload with additional font and font size parameters I could reproduce the issue.

#### The actual issue

The problem is not related to the specific font or text you used, it is related to the `setValue` overload you use:

- `PdfFormField.setValue(String)` (unless the field is a button field) iterates through the whole hierarchy of descendants of the current field and calls another `setValue` overload for each descendant and eventually also the current field.
- On the other hand `PdfFormField.setValue(String, boolean)` and `PdfFormField.setValue(String, PdfFont, float)` assume the current field to actually be the single widget to add an appearance to.

Thus, any form field with multiple widgets (or even a field with a single widget which merely is not merged with the field) will not retrieve a proper appearance for its widgets if merely a `setValue` overload of the latter kind is called for it.

#### A work-around

With the above said in mind, a work-around would be to somehow work with the single parameter `setValue` overload. One can do so by setting the font and font size explicitly to the form field, simply replace

```
textField.setValue("שלום", font, 11.0f);
```

by

```
textField.setFont(font);
textField.setFontSize(11f);
textField.setValue("שלום");
```

*([SetTextField](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext7/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/itext7/form/SetTextField.java#L122) test `testSetFontAndTextToFieldWithManyVisualizationsWorkAround`)*

Now the fields indeed are filled and their content is present in the flattened result.

Unfortunately another issue pops up here: The letters appear in the wrong order. RTL languages seem not to be supported here using the basic iText components alone. Probably using the [pdfCalligraph](https://itextpdf.com/products/itext-7/pdfcalligraph) add-on module adds support for Hebrew etc. but I don't know.

## The original answer to the original question

I cannot reproduce the issue with your example document.

I change the field value like this

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(resource);
PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(reader, new PdfWriter(outputStream));
PdfAcroForm acroForm = PdfAcroForm.getAcroForm(pdfDocument, false);

PdfFormField testField = acroForm.getField("test");
testField.setValue("My test text...");

acroForm.flattenFields();

pdfDocument.close();
```

*([SetTextField](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext7/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/itext7/form/SetTextField.java#L43) test `testSetTextToFieldWithManyVisualizations`)*

but the result is the expected:

> [image: page 1]
> [image: page 2]

All three instances of the field are filled in. This works both with flattening and without, and it works both with 7.1.4 and with the current 7.1.5-SNAPSHOT.

One problem, though, looking at the internals of the result PDF one sees

[image]

The value **V** is set both in the abstract field and in each widget. It should only be in the field.

Comment: I didn't think setting complex strings was related to the issue. I updated the question.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! The reversed character behavior is expected when PDFcalligraph is not used, that's fine. I just don't know what to think with iText 7. I'm doing an evaluation during the trial period and you made me discover multiple issues with basic PDF forms use cases... Are you reporting all this behaviors to iText?

Comment: *"Are you reporting all this behaviors to iText?"* - iText develpers are reading and responding here, too, so they'll be aware. Additionally I had forwarded a link to your previous question to them explicitly.